# Specifying BigQuery dataset/table's name on AutoML Batch Prediction results

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-automl

Basically I want to specify BigQuery dataset/table's name on the batch prediction result of AutoML.

But looking at the following documentation, the dataset and the table's name are automatically generated. And a new dataset will be created for each batch prediction executed.

> https://cloud.google.com/automl-tables/docs/predict-batch#bq-results

Looking at the following documentation, only projectId can be specified on the BigQuery destination:

> https://cloud.google.com/automl/docs/reference/rest/v1beta1/BigQueryDestination

I plan to do the batch prediction automatically on a weekly basis. To make the prediction results "cleaner", I want to group all the prediction results into one dataset, instead of having a separate dataset for each batch prediction.

Is there any way to get it done via the provided API?

Comment: Did you figure out how to automate this?

Comment: After the batch prediction is completed, the generated dataset/table's name will be returned in the response of "operations" API (get). So I aggregated the result into a single table by using the returned name in a separate process.

https://cloud.google.com/automl/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.operations/get

Answer (score 1):

If it's not documented there is no way to do it via the API, then, if you want to create all output in the same dataset, you can send the result to a bucket directory [1], this way it will create multiple CSV files [2] in your Google Cloud Storage Bucket.

Therefore, now you have to create a way to read the new files from this bucket and create a new table in the desired dataset each time you make a batch prediction. 
Here is a documentation that shows you how to create a new table from a CSV file in Google Cloud Storage [3].

The other way is to make a transfer from the new created table to the desired dataset [4], but you have to do it evary time a new table is created.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/automl-tables/docs/predict-batch#using_csv_files_in

[2] https://cloud.google.com/automl-tables/docs/predict-batch#csv-results

[3] https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/external-data-cloud-storage#creating_and_querying_a_permanent_external_table

[4] https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-tables#copying_a_single_source_table